# compiling multiple .jsx files into one .js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way of compiling multiple reactjs `.jsx` files into one `.js` file in one step?

something like:

`jsxtool compile ./src/*.jsx  --out app.js`

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An easy way is to use gulp. Run `npm install gulp` along with `gulp-react` and `gulp-concat` and make your gulpfile.js look like this:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var react = require('gulp-react');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
gulp.task('default', function () {
return gulp.src('components/**')
    .pipe(concat('singlefile.js'))
    .pipe(react())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Now run `gulp` and boom, a single file!

Comment: I guess i could .pipe(minify) or something like that as well. How do i make it watch the files and gulp after i make a change?

Comment: you could do that with uglify: https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-uglify. As for watching, take a look at https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch

Comment: What does `.pipe(react())` means in this?

Comment: OK got it. It Reactifies the combined output jsx code into simple js

Answer (score 4):

This is the direct answer, which you can put in a shell script (say `jsx-all.sh`).

```
find $1 -iname '*.jsx' | xargs cat | jsx
```

And usage:

```
jsx-all.sh src/ > app.js
```

---

The better answer is to use commonjs modules.  See browserify with reactify or webpack with jsx-loader.  This is what most people in the react comunity use.

Comment: Thanks.  And now i have 3 problems ;) commonjs, gulp and browserify . Got some reading todo.

Comment: You say problems, I say solutions :-)